# JS Javascript variable leaking

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code for a html presentation slide player, but variable "b" somehow is getting numbers added to it, and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
function loadSong(songname){
    b = 1;
    console.log(b);
    var html = slidehtml(songname,b);
    if(vr_on){
        vr.innerHTML = html;
    }
    display.innerHTML = html;
    window.addEventListener("keydown", function(){
        if(event.which == 37){
            b = b - 1;
            if(b <= 0){b = 1;}
            if(vr_on){
                vr.innerHTML = slidehtml(songname,b);
            }
            display.innerHTML = slidehtml(songname,b);
            console.log(b);
        }
        if(event.which == 39){
            b = b + 1;
            if(b > song_count(songname)){b = song_count(songname);}
            if(vr_on){
                vr.innerHTML = slidehtml(songname,b);
            }
            console.log(b);
            display.innerHTML = slidehtml(songname,b);
        }
    });
 }
```

Also, here are the other functions used in the script above

```
function song_count(a){
    if(a == 'pitb'){return 8;}
    if(a == 'hgta'){return 16;}
    if(a == 'hpdo'){return 4;}
    if(a == 'ismp'){return 8;}
    if(a == 'saip'){return 8;}
    if(a == 'ogsj'){return 8;}
    if(a == 'torc'){return 12;}
    if(a == 'sufj'){return 6;}
    if(a == 'tmlb'){return 4;}
    if(a == 'gwsn'){return 2;}
    if(a == 'jlm0'){return 6;}
    if(a == 'tpoc'){return 8;}
    if(a == 'wisc'){return 4;}
    if(a == 'ynic'){return 13;}
    if(a == 's_fs'){return 40;}
}
function showSlide(a) {
    var c = "<img src='slides/" + a + ".jpeg'>";
    if(vr_on){
        vr.innerHTML = c;
    }
    display.innerHTML = c;
 }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Also, it works fine if song_count('pitb'); but not if song_count('ismp');

Here is the FULL code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Display</title>
    </head>
    <body id='con'>
        <style>
        .btn{
        background:grey;
        color:white;
        border-right:2px solid black;
        display:inline-block;
        padding:6px;
        padding-left:12px;
        padding-right:12px;
        }
        .menubar{width:calc(100% - 48px);
        margin-left:12px;}
        .btn:hover{
        background:black;
        cursor:pointer;
        }
        body{padding:0;margin:0;}
        #container,#viewer{
        width:50%;
        max-width:50%;
        position:absolute;
        min-height:100vh;
        top:0;
        }
        .sbtn{font-size:14pt;color:rgb(120,150,255);text-decoration:underline;}
        .sbtn:hover{color:rgb(100,120,200);cursor:pointer;}
        .songs{
        width:calc(100% - 48px);
        margin-left:12px;
        padding:12px;
        background:white;
        }
        img{width:100%;}
        #viewer{right:0;background:black;color:white;}
        #container{background:rgb(240,240,240);left:0;}
        </style>
        <div id="container">
            <h1 style="text-align:center">Controller Menu</h1>
            <div class='menubar'><div class='btn' onclick='home()'><p>Home</p></div><div class='btn' onclick='start()'><p>Start Countdown Video</p></div><div class='btn' onclick='mlv()'><p>Main Loop Video</p></div></div>
            <div class='songs'>
                <h1>Songs</h1>
                <div class='sbtn' onclick='loadSong("pitb")'><p>Song 1</p></div>
                <div class='sbtn' onclick='loadSong("hgta")'><p>Song 2</p></div>
                <div class='sbtn' onclick='loadSong("hpdo")'><p>Song 3</p></div>
                <div class='sbtn' onclick='loadSong("ismp")'><p>Song 4</p></div>
                <div class='sbtn' onclick='loadSong("ogsj")'><p>Song 5</p></div>
                <div class='sbtn' onclick='loadSong("sufj")'><p>Song 6</p></div>
                <div class='sbtn' onclick='loadSong("torc")'><p>Song 7</p></div>
                <div class='sbtn' onclick='loadSong("ynic")'><p>Song 8</p></div>
                <div class='sbtn' onclick='loadSong("tmlb")'><p>Song 9</p></div>
                <div class='sbtn' onclick='loadSong("gwsn")'><p>Song 10</p></div>
                <div class='sbtn' onclick='loadSong("jlm0")'><p>Song 11</p></div>
                <div class='sbtn' onclick='loadSong("tpoc")'><p>Song 12</p></div>
                <div class='sbtn' onclick='loadSong("wisc")'><p>Song 13</p></div>
            </div><br>

            <div class='songs'>
                <h1>Quick Message</h1>
                <div style="padding:8px;background:grey;color:white;margin-top:6px;" onclick="openQuickMessage()">Open quick message</div>
            </div><br>
        </div><div id='viewer'></div>
        <script>
            function song_count(a){
            if(a == 'pitb'){return 8;}
            if(a == 'hgta'){return 16;}
            if(a == 'hpdo'){return 4;}
            if(a == 'ismp'){return 8;}
            if(a == 'saip'){return 8;}
            if(a == 'ogsj'){return 8;}
            if(a == 'torc'){return 12;}
            if(a == 'sufj'){return 6;}
            if(a == 'tmlb'){return 4;}
            if(a == 'gwsn'){return 2;}
            if(a == 'jlm0'){return 6;}
            if(a == 'tpoc'){return 8;}
            if(a == 'wisc'){return 4;}
            if(a == 'ynic'){return 13;}
            if(a == 's_fs'){return 40;}
            }


            function createDisplay(a) {
                if(a === true) {
                    vr_on = true;
                    vr = document.getElementById('viewer');
                    vr.innerHTML = '<h1 style="text-align:center;">VR is on!</h1>';
                }
                else {
                    vr_on = false;
                }
                nwObj = window.open();
                nw = nwObj.document;
                nw.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Display</title></head><body><style>body{overflow:hidden;padding:0;margin:0;}#con{background:black;color:white;height:100vh;position:absolute;top:0;width:100%;max-width:100%;}img{width:100%;}.lds-roller{display:inline-block;position:relative;width:64px;height:64px;}.lds-roller div{animation:lds-roller 1.2s cubic-bezier(.5,0,.5,1) infinite;transform-origin:32px 32px}.lds-roller div:after{content:" ";display:block;position:absolute;width:6px;height:6px;border-radius:50%;background:#fff;margin:-3px 0 0 -3px}.lds-roller div:nth-child(1){animation-delay:-36ms}.lds-roller div:nth-child(1):after{top:50px;left:50px}.lds-roller div:nth-child(2){animation-delay:-72ms}.lds-roller div:nth-child(2):after{top:54px;left:45px}.lds-roller div:nth-child(3){animation-delay:-108ms}.lds-roller div:nth-child(3):after{top:57px;left:39px}.lds-roller div:nth-child(4){animation-delay:-144ms}.lds-roller div:nth-child(4):after{top:58px;left:32px}.lds-roller div:nth-child(5){animation-delay:-.18s}.lds-roller div:nth-child(5):after{top:57px;left:25px}.lds-roller div:nth-child(6){animation-delay:-216ms}.lds-roller div:nth-child(6):after{top:54px;left:19px}.lds-roller div:nth-child(7){animation-delay:-252ms}.lds-roller div:nth-child(7):after{top:50px;left:14px}.lds-roller div:nth-child(8){animation-delay:-288ms}.lds-roller div:nth-child(8):after{top:45px;left:10px}@keyframes lds-roller{0%{transform:rotate(0)}100%{transform:rotate(360deg)}}</style><div id="con"><p onclick="window.opener.fullscreen();">Fullscreen...</p><div style="position:absolute;left:50%;margin-left:-32px;top:50%;margin-top:-32px;"><div class="lds-roller"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div></div></div></body></html>');
                nw.close();
                display = nw.getElementById('con');
            }
            function fullscreen() {
                display.requestFullscreen();
            }
            function sendmsg(){
                var a = "<br><br><br><br><h1 style='text-align:center'>" + qm.getElementById("msg").value + "</h1>";
                if(vr_on){
                    vr.innerHTML = a;
                }
                display.innerHTML = a;
            }
            function start(){
                display.innerHTML = '<video id="vid" src="out.mp4" style="width:100%;position:absolute;top:50%;transform: translateY(-50%);" preload="auto"></video>';
                nw.getElementById('vid').play();
                if(vr_on){
                    vr.innerHTML = '<video id="vid_vr" src="out.mp4" style="width:100%;" preload="auto" muted></video>';
                    document.getElementById('vid_vr').play();
                }
            }
            function mlv(){
                display.innerHTML = '<video id="vid1" src="out1.mp4" style="width:100%;top:50%;transform: translateY(-50%);" loop preload="auto"></video>';
                nw.getElementById('vid1').play();
                if(vr_on){
                    vr.innerHTML = '<video id="vid1_vr" src="out1.mp4" style="width:100%;position:absolute;top:50%;transform: translateY(-50%);" loop preload="auto" muted></video>';
                    document.getElementById('vid1_vr').play();
                }
            }
            function home(){
                if(vr_on){
                    vr.innerHTML = '<h1 style="text-align:center">Home</h1>';
                }
                display.innerHTML = '<h1 style="text-align:center">Home</h1>';
            }
            function showSlide(a) {
                var c = "<img src='slides/" + a + ".jpeg'>";
                if(vr_on){
                    vr.innerHTML = c;
                }
                display.innerHTML = c;
            }
            function loadSong(a){
                var b = 1;
                console.log("Start: " + b);
                var html = slidehtml(a,b);
                if(vr_on){
                    vr.innerHTML = html;
                }
                display.innerHTML = html;
                window.addEventListener("keydown", function(){
                    if(event.which == 37){
                        b = b - 1;
                        if(b <= 0){b = 1;}
                        if(vr_on){
                            vr.innerHTML = slidehtml(a,b);
                        }
                        display.innerHTML = slidehtml(a,b);
                        console.log(b);
                    }
                    if(event.which == 39){
                        console.log("Right: " + b);
                        b = b + 1;
                        if(b > song_count(a)){b = song_count(a);}
                        console.log("Right After: " + b);
                        if(vr_on){
                            vr.innerHTML = slidehtml(a,b);
                        }
                        console.log(b);
                        display.innerHTML = slidehtml(a,b);
                    }
                });
            }
            function quickMessageFocus() {
                qm.getElementById('msg').focus();
            }
            function openQuickMessage() {
                '<input id="msg" tpye="text" style="width:calc(100% - 12px);padding:6px;">';
                qmObj = window.open('about:blank','quickMessage','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,width=500px,height=70px');
                qm = qmObj.document;
                qm.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Quick Message</title></head><body onload="window.opener.quickMessageFocus()" ><style>body{overflow:hidden;padding:0;margin:0;}#qm{background:white;color:black;height:100vh;position:absolute;top:0;width:100%;max-width:100%;}img{width:100%;}.lds-roller{display:inline-block;position:relative;width:64px;height:64px;}.lds-roller div{animation:lds-roller 1.2s cubic-bezier(.5,0,.5,1) infinite;transform-origin:32px 32px}.lds-roller div:after{content:" ";display:block;position:absolute;width:6px;height:6px;border-radius:50%;background:#fff;margin:-3px 0 0 -3px}.lds-roller div:nth-child(1){animation-delay:-36ms}.lds-roller div:nth-child(1):after{top:50px;left:50px}.lds-roller div:nth-child(2){animation-delay:-72ms}.lds-roller div:nth-child(2):after{top:54px;left:45px}.lds-roller div:nth-child(3){animation-delay:-108ms}.lds-roller div:nth-child(3):after{top:57px;left:39px}.lds-roller div:nth-child(4){animation-delay:-144ms}.lds-roller div:nth-child(4):after{top:58px;left:32px}.lds-roller div:nth-child(5){animation-delay:-.18s}.lds-roller div:nth-child(5):after{top:57px;left:25px}.lds-roller div:nth-child(6){animation-delay:-216ms}.lds-roller div:nth-child(6):after{top:54px;left:19px}.lds-roller div:nth-child(7){animation-delay:-252ms}.lds-roller div:nth-child(7):after{top:50px;left:14px}.lds-roller div:nth-child(8){animation-delay:-288ms}.lds-roller div:nth-child(8):after{top:45px;left:10px}@keyframes lds-roller{0%{transform:rotate(0)}100%{transform:rotate(360deg)}}</style><div id="qm"><p onclick="window.opener.sendmsg();">Fullscreen...</p><div style="position:absolute;left:50%;margin-left:-32px;top:50%;margin-top:-32px;"><div class="lds-roller"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div></div></div></body></html>');
                qm.close();
                quickMessage = qm.getElementById('qm');
                quickMessage.innerHTML = "<div style=''><input style='width:calc(70% - 12px);margin-left:12px;margin-top:25px' type='text' id='msg'><input style='width:calc(30% - 24px);margin-left:12px;padding:6px' onclick='window.opener.sendmsg()' type='submit' value='Send to screen ->'></div>";
                qmObj.addEventListener('keydown',function(event){
                    if(event.which == 13){
                        sendmsg();
                        qmObj.close();
                    }
                    if(event.which == 9){
                        qmObj.close();
                    }
                });
            }
            window.addEventListener('keydown',function(event){
                if(event.which == 81){
                    openQuickMessage();
                }
            });
            function slidehtml(a,c){return("<img src='slides/" + a + "43" + c + ".jpeg'>");}
            window.addEventListener('load',function(){
                createDisplay(true);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I believe is happening that every time you are calling the `loadSong` function, the `key down` event is being attached, which is already attached in general by the previous/prior function call, what I suggest you to do is take the attaching of listener outside the function:

then you loadSong function will be:

```
function loadSong(a){
     var b = 1;
     console.log("Start: " + b);
     var html = slidehtml(a,b);
     if(vr_on){
     vr.innerHTML = html;
     }
     display.innerHTML = html;
}
```

Comment: How would you pass b to eventlistener?

Comment: I ended up using globals for b and a so that window.addEventListner could use them

Comment: yeah, I was just going to edit my answer to that, plus, using an global hash object could also help, you may initialize it with 1, if you need to use the values of `b` with respect of `a` in future.
example, `var global_hash = {'pitb': 1, hgta: 1, etc..}` (not much familiar with js syntax)

Answer (score 2):

You have a global `b`, because you do not define this variable inside of a function.

Comment: Why does that matter though?

Comment: yoh take one variable for all songs. btw, naming just `a` and `b` is not really helpfull, if the variable do not denote sorting values, for example.

Comment: So if I change it to "var b" instead of "b", it will work?

Comment: it looks like it, because you create a closure with the events.

Comment: suppose you call loadSong for your first song it gets, B some value. but then for if that function is called again, now the new song expect the value of B to 1 be but instead it is some value.

Comment: I am using console.log(b), so I know that b always starts at 1 when "loadSong()" is called.  But after I click an arrow key, it logs like: (2)8, 6, 2.

Comment: The `var b` alone would most likely not solve the problem as the OP does `window.addEventListener("keydown", function(){` for each `loadSong`.

Comment: so like how's the `loadsong` is being called? also think it like this, suppose first time you call the `loadsong` the listener is already attached to `keydown event`, and just a hypothesis, maybe the precedence for event listener is more than function call.

Comment: agreed with @t.niese

Comment: @SethB, please add the html part as well.

Comment: Yes, now it works, but now it is running the script like 8 or 16 times every time I run "loadSong()"

Comment: because of to much events for window.